# How to manage use content on website

Tags: php, html, database, web

so I have recently gained some interest in how websites work. I am trying to learn how websites such as facebook and twitter manage their user contents. I have tried looking on google but my lack of correct terminology makes it harder for me to find anything useful. So can someone suggest me a book/good read/video/article that would explain me how these things work? I have basic knowledge of database and some web developing terminology.

what I want to know is, how websites store user posts on the database and how you can store comments and other related stuff to the post.

Also whats the correct term for this type of websites? So i can do some more research on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should start searching some documentation on OOP, webapp and some tutorials on how frameworks work (like Django or Flask, if you're familiar with python)

Comment: awesome! I will start looking into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Learning about designing relational databases will help you understand how posts and comments are stored in a database and how to relate comments to posts, etc.

Learning about web development will help you understand how websites can use server-side languages like Python or PHP to retrieve and store data from the database and present it as a website.

My favorite book for beginning PHP web development was "PHP and MySQL Web Development" by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson

The best book I found for learning about databases was "Inside Relational Databases with Examples in Access".

Comment: awesome! thanks alot, i have done some research in php for server side. Will start looking into designing databases. Thanks again